# Prove $f\in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ and $\int_a^b f\ d\alpha = f(s)$ with the following conditions.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If $a<s<b$, $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$, $f$ is continuous at $s$, and $\alpha(x)=I(x-s)$, then prove that:
$$f\in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$$
and
$$\int_a^b f\ d\alpha = f(s)$$

$I$ is a *unit step function*.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\mathscr{P}$ is a partition such that $s\in \mathscr{P}$. Let $s=x_{i-1}$. Then

$U(\mathscr{P},f,\alpha)=\sum_{i=1}^n M_i \Delta\alpha_i=M_i$ which comes from the definition of the unit step function. (Do you see how?)
$L(\mathscr{P},f,\alpha)=\sum_{i=1}^n m_i \Delta\alpha_i=m_i$

Therefore,
$U(\mathscr{P},f,\alpha)-L(\mathscr{P},f,\alpha)=M_i-m_i\ \ \ \ \ \text{(I)}$

$f$ is continuous at $s$, thus
$\forall \varepsilon >0,\ \exists \delta >0;\ \ |x-s|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(s)|<\varepsilon. \ \ \ \ \ \text{(II)}$

Let $||P||<\delta $. Then

$M_i-m_i=\sup_{x_{i-1}\leq x,y\leq x_i} |f(x)-f(y)|$
$\ \ \ \ \leq \sup_{s=x_{i-1}\leq x,y\leq x_i} (|f(x)-f(s)|+|f(s)-f(y)|)$
$\ \ \ \ \stackrel{\text{(II)}}{\leq} \varepsilon +\varepsilon = 2\varepsilon$

Hence, from (I)
$$U(\mathscr{P},f,\alpha)-L(\mathscr{P},f,\alpha)<2\varepsilon$$
And from Rudin's PoMA's Theorem 6.6, we have
$$f\in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$$

Now about the equality:

$\int_a^b f\ d\alpha\leq U(\mathscr{P},f,\alpha)=M_i \stackrel{\text{(II)}}{<}f(s)+\varepsilon\ \ \ \text{(III)}$
$\int_a^b f\ d\alpha\geq L(\mathscr{P},f,\alpha)=m_i \stackrel{\text{(II)}}{>}f(s)-\varepsilon\ \ \ \text{(IV)}$

From (III) and (IV), 
$$\int_a^b f\ d\alpha = f(s)$$

$\square$